# Adjective for someone unable to cope with the past

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives, synonyms, descriptive-grammar

I'm looking for a word that could describe a character's personality in the sense that he is someone who (re)lives the past too much and is uncapable of overcoming it and moving on with his life.

Any suggestions?

I appreciate it.

Comment: Stuck in the past? Obsessed with the past?

Comment: Fixated, retrospective, mired, obsessed, timid, regretful, nostalgic

Comment: "Haunted" is often used in this sense.

Comment: Hide-bound implies a strict adherence to a way of doing things, so relates. Stuck also can convey a similar meaning in some cases.

Answer (score 2):

Consider,

[***backward-looking***](http://www.wordreference.com/fren/pass%C3%A9iste)

> Concerned with the past rather than the present and future [FOD](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/backward-looking)

[***living-in-the-past***](https://www.google.fr/search?sclient=tablet-gws&biw=790&bih=518&noj=1&tbm=bks&q=%22living+in+the+past+attitude%22&oq=%22living+in+the+past+attitude%22&gs_l=tablet-gws.3...14512.27404.0.28248.16.16.0.0.0.0.2341.6741.2-1j1j6-1j1j1j1.6.0....0...1c.1.64.tablet-gws..10.2.2938.MwJPeKGPx6s)

> live in the past: *Fig.* to live while dwelling on past memories without participating in the present or planning for the future. *You are just living in the past. Join us in the twenty-first century*. [McGraw-Hill Dictionary of American Idioms and Phrasal Verbs](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/live+in+the+past)

***past-ridden***

> ridden: *adj.* dominated, harassed, or obsessed by. Often used in combination: *disease-ridden*; *grief-ridden*. [American Heritage® Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/ridden)

[***stick-in-the-mud***](https://www.google.fr/search?q=stick+in+the+mud&biw=1024&bih=672&noj=1&prmd=isvn&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjS15K7jobLAhVKhhoKHaczBMAQ_AUIBygB)

> Someone who has old-fashioned ideas or who does not like trying new or exciting things. [M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/stick%E2%80%93in%E2%80%93the%E2%80%93mud)